# What is a proper way to write an interceptor for the resource?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I have a need to transform response from service on each get, save, update. I've created a resource and added a transformer that gets executed, but the structure of object being returned is not the same as when I don't use transformer. Here I am talking about the structure of the response, not the object I am transforming.
Here is my resource:

```
angular.module('app')
   .factory('Insureds', ['$resource', 'config',  function ($resource, config) {

       function transform(response) {

           var insured = response.data.insured;


           return response;
       }

       var memberServicesHostName = config.memberServicesHostName;
       return $resource(memberServicesHostName + '/insureds/:insuredId', null,
       {
           'get': {
               method: 'GET', 'withCredentials': true, interceptor:
               {
                    response: function (response) { return transform(response).data; }
               }
           },
           'update': { method: 'PUT', 'withCredentials': true },
           'save': { method: 'POST', 'withCredentials': true }
       });
   }]);
```

When I don't use transformer "insured" is on the first level when the promise gets resolved it resolves as an instance of insured object. But with transformer there is wrapper object, that contains insured and responseStatus properties. It probably has to do with what I am returning from the "reponse" in the interceptor. What should one return, original response, like I am doing, or response.data, or response.resource.insured? I am confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default response interceptor is like this:

```
function defaultResponseInterceptor(response) {
  return response.resource;
}
```

Therefore, if you would like to preserve the default behaviour, you have to return `response.resource` instead of `response.data`:

```
return $resource(memberServicesHostName + '/insureds/:insuredId', null, {
  get: {
    method: 'GET',
    withCredentials: true,
    interceptor: {
      response: function (response) {
        return transform(response).resource;
      }
    }
  },
  ...
```

Hope this helps.